# Unexpected failure during lint analysis of module-info.class

Tags: android, lint

has anyone else seen this error:

```
Errors found:

  /home/ligi/git/walleth/app/module-info.class: Error: Unexpected failure during lint analysis of module-info.class (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)

  Stack: NullPointerException:InvalidPackageDetector.checkClass(InvalidPackageDetector.java:112)←AsmVisitor.runClassDetectors(AsmVisitor.java:154)←LintDriver.runClassDetectors(LintDriver.kt:1461)←LintDriver.checkClasses(LintDriver.kt:1329)←LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.kt:1096)←LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.kt:895)←LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.kt:416)←LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.java:235)

  You can set environment variable LINT_PRINT_STACKTRACE=true to dump a full stacktrace to stdout. [LintError]
  Applies to variants: noGethNoFirebaseForFDroidOnlineDebug
  /home/ligi/git/walleth/app/module-info.class: Error: Unexpected failure during lint analysis of module-info.class (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)

  Stack: NullPointerException:
```

I only found this project facing the same problem:

https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/issues/1730

any workaround would be nice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Android tooling for Android Studio 3.3 and earlier chokes on `module-info.class` files that are required by the [Java Platform Module System](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/) (JPMS). Which is mind boggling considering that Java 9, the first version that shipped with the JPMS, came out in September 2017 and Java 11, the first LTS release with the JPMS, came out in September 2018, around 4 months before Android Studio 3.3. The relevant bug in the Android issue tracker: [[lint] InvalidPackage crashes on module-info.class from byte-buddy](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117686566)

So, workarounds:

- Upgrade the Android tooling to a beta of 3.4 or later. I tested 3.4.0-beta05 on one of my projects and it worked well.
- Downgrade whatever library you're using to a version that does not yet support the JPMS (i.e. does not include a `module-info.java`).

Comment: Their release cycle is terrible. Per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117686566#comment4 they fixed it in November 2018 and just haven't pushed it out to the stable release or gotten out a new stable release. It's a recurring issue with Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

To ignore this error, I defined this in my `lint.xml`:

```
<issue id="LintError">
    <ignore regexp=".*module-info\.class.*"/>
</issue>
```

The above mentioned workarounds did not work for me:

- Updating Android build tools to 3.4.1 didn't help
- I couldn't downgrade the dependency that lead to this problem

Comment: This didn't work for me with build tools 3.5.3 (the error persisted).